# Multiple wait on the same lock

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I am a bit confused about locking. Specifically, this code here from wikipedia about the consumer producer problem.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem#Example_in_C.2B.2B

What happened if there are more than 1 producer wait to add to the queue? If consumer consumed some job from the queue and issues a notification to indicate the queue is not full, they all try to push a job in the queue, that would require queue.push method to be thread safe. Since they could all modify queue, this code could break. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you're missing the fact that `xmutex` is locked so only one producer can push anything at a time.

When you wait on a `condition_variable` you must pass it a locked mutex, which will be unlocked while waiting. When the wait call returns the mutex will be re-locked.

Although all producers will get notified by the `is_not_full.notify_all();` event, and so will all wake up, they will only be able to re-acquire the lock on `xmutex` one at a time. That's the whole point of a mutex.

Comment: On top of that, you usually only have one producer anyway. If one already has many producers running in parallel, they could as well take the consumers' job, too. The main point in producer/consumer (with very, very few exceptions) is to evenly distribute _n_ parallelizable tasks onto _m_ worker threads or execution cores. If one expects several producers, a semaphore would be a much saner implementation (avoiding the thundering herd problem that you mentioned).

Comment: This implementation still got another problem. If there are more producer than the max_products, which equals to 10 in this example, there is a chance there are 10 producer waiting, and when they all got waked, they would all add to the queue, although it is thread-safe, the number of product in the queue can be more than 10,  which is maximum allowed.